# Are affine hypersurfaces connected?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, let $n \geq 2$, let $f \in P = k [x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be a non-constant polynomial, and let $F \in P [x_{n + 1}]$ be the homogenization of $f$ with respect to $x_{n + 1}$.

It is well-known that the projective hypersurface $V_+ (F) \subset \mathbb{P}_k^n$ is connected.

Is it also true that the affine hypersurface $V (f) \subset \mathbb{A}_k^n$ is connected when we consider $V_+ (F)$ as the projective closure of $V (f)$ via the natural immersion $\mathbb{A}_k^n \to \mathbb{P}_k^n$, $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto [x_1: \ldots: x_n: 1]$?

Comment: I see, since $x_1$ is idempotent in $P / (x_1^2 - x_1)$ the affine surface cannot be connected.
Could you please post it as answer, so I can close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for example consider $f = x_1(x_1 - 1)$. Then $V(f)$ has connected components $V(x_1)$ and $V(x_1 - 1)$, each isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}$.